# Can the mesh select mode menu converted to a pie menu in Blender 2.72?

Tags: interface, customization, pie-menu

The [release notes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.72/UI/Pie_Menus) mention that it is possible to add pie menus. But I'm not sure how to do it.

How could I convert the mesh select mode menu's appearance:

[image]

to this?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some Basics are documented in the Blender Wiki, see:

- [Creating Pie Menus](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.72/UI/Pie_Menus)
- [Coding Pie Menus](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Source/UI/Pie_Menus)

Below you find a complete, briefly commented and fully working mini example addon. Just place the code below into a file named

```
whatever_name_you_like.py
```

and then Install/Enable this python file as a regular Addon.

Notes:

- The name of the file is not important, however the appendix '.py' is essential to mark this as a python file.
- You do not need to enable the "Pie Menus Official" Addon in order to get your own Pie menus to work properly!

### Begin of the code:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "My Pies",
    "author": "My Name",
    "version": (1, 1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 72, 0),
    "description": "My Pie menu",
    "category": "Object" }

import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu

# Implements an edit mode selection pie

class VIEW3D_PIE_template(Menu):
    # label is displayed at the center of the pie menu.
    bl_label  = "Select Mode" # Appears as Pie title
    bl_idname = "mesh.mypie"  # Used to refer (see below)

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        pie = layout.menu_pie()
        # operator_enum will just spread all available options
        # for the type enum of the operator on the pie
        pie.operator_enum("mesh.select_mode", "type")

addon_keymaps = [] # Store keymaps to use in unregister()

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PIE_template)

    # Define a keyboard shortcut (for Mesh Edit mode)
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name="Mesh")

    # Open the pie when you press CTRL SHIFT E:
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new("wm.call_menu_pie", 'E', 'PRESS', shift=True, ctrl=True)
    kmi.properties.name="mesh.mypie"
    addon_keymaps.append((km,kmi)) # Store keymap


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PIE_template)

    #use stored keymaps to unregister
    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: you can add icon_only=True to not have the text

Answer (score 5):

I know this has being answered correctly by Gaia Clary , but I needed to do a similar thing, and it took me a little while to find the exact code needed, so here it is. 
I wanted to be able to pick some (but not all of the mesh select menus).The code below shows how I achieved this.

```
    bl_info = {
    "name": "Yomi_Pie_Menus",
    "author": "Oluwayomi Longe",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 73),
    "description": "Custom Pie Menus",
    "category": "3D View",}

import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu

# Pie Select Mode - Tab
class PieTabMode(Menu):
    bl_idname = "pie.tabmode"
    bl_label = "Select Mode"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        pie = layout.menu_pie()

        #4 - LEFT
        # use the commented line below if you want to toggle Edit and object mode
        #pie.operator("object.editmode_toggle", text="Edit/Object", icon='OBJECT_DATAMODE')          

        pie.operator("object.mode_set", text="Edit", icon='EDITMODE_HLT').mode='EDIT' 
        #6 - RIGHT
        pie.operator("object.mode_set", text="Object", icon='OBJECT_DATAMODE').mode='OBJECT'

        #3 - BOTTOM
        box = pie.split().column()
        row = box.row(align=True)
        box.operator("mesh.select_mode", text="Vertex", icon='VERTEXSEL').type = 'VERT'
        box.operator("mesh.select_mode", text="Edge", icon='EDGESEL').type = 'EDGE'
        box.operator("mesh.select_mode", text="Face", icon='FACESEL').type = 'FACE'
        #8 - TOP
        #pie.operator("sculpt.sculptmode_toggle", text="Sculpt", icon='SCULPTMODE_HLT')
        pie.operator("object.mode_set", text="Sculpt", icon='SCULPTMODE_HLT').mode='SCULPT'


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(PieTabMode)    
    # or any other classes you add

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager

    if wm.keyconfigs.addon:
        #Select Mode
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Object Non-modal')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new('wm.call_menu_pie', 'TAB', 'PRESS')
        kmi.properties.name = "pie.tabmode"    


def unregister(): 
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PieTabMode)
     # or any other classes you add

    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this video: http://vimeo.com/103321600
The actual tutorial starts at about two minutes. Hope that helps! :)

By chance the video describes exactly how to create the mesh select mode as pie.menu.
With the pie-menus a new python script template has been added, it is accessible from the text editor:

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep that in mind. In this case though, I thought that it would be too complicated to explain in a text answer and would be better to link to the video.

Answer (score 1):

And here another, using the icon field of the bpy.types.EnumProperty(). I think the template provided now in TextEditor is a little sparse, this might help.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu

class VIEW3D_PIE_SV_ops(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "nodes.pie_menu_enum"
    bl_label = "Add Quick Node"

    mode_options = [
        ("option1", "option1", "", "CURVE_DATA", 0),
        ("option2", "option2", "", "", 1),
        ("option3", "option3", "", "", 2)
    ]

    selected_mode = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        items=mode_options,
        description="offers....",
        default="option1"
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        print('added ', self.selected_mode)
        return {'FINISHED'}


class VIEW3D_PIE_template(Menu):
    # label is displayed at the center of the pie menu.
    bl_label = "Select Mode"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        pie = layout.menu_pie()
        pie.operator_enum("nodes.pie_menu_enum", "selected_mode")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu_pie(name="VIEW3D_PIE_template")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just find it, and I think i have a nice code from my project for it.

I wrote also one for bone selection and one for selection in object mode

[image: My Selectons Menu]

```
# Pie Selection Edit Mode
class PieSelectionsEM(Menu):
bl_idname = "pie.selectionsem"
bl_label = "Pie Selections Edit Mode"

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    pie = layout.menu_pie()
    # 4 - LEFT
    pie.operator("view3d.select_border", text="Border Select",
                icon='BORDER_RECT')
    # 6 - RIGHT
    pie.menu("object.selectloopselection", text="Select Loop Menu", icon='LOOPSEL')
    # 2 - BOTTOM
    box = pie.split().column()
    row = box.row(align=True)
    row.operator("mesh.select_less", text="Select LESS", icon='DISCLOSURE_TRI_DOWN')     
    row.operator("mesh.select_more", text="Select MORE", icon='DISCLOSURE_TRI_RIGHT')
    box.operator("mesh.select_nth", text="Checker DESelect", icon='DOTSDOWN')

    # 8 - TOP
    pie.operator("mesh.select_all", text="Select All/None",
                icon='RESTRICT_SELECT_OFF').action = 'TOGGLE'
    # 7 - TOP - LEFT
    #pie.operator("mesh.select_all", text="Select All Toggle",
    #            icon='ARROW_LEFTRIGHT').action = 'TOGGLE'

    pie.operator("mesh.select_linked", text="linked", icon='LINKED')
    # 9 - TOP - RIGHT
    pie.operator("mesh.select_all", text="Invert Selection",
                icon='FULLSCREEN_EXIT').action = 'INVERT'
    # 1 - BOTTOM - LEFT
    pie.operator("view3d.select_circle", text="Circle Select",
                icon='BORDER_LASSO')
    # 3 - BOTTOM - RIGHT

    box = pie.split().column()
    row = box.row(align=True)
    row.operator("mesh.select_mode", text="Select Vertex", icon='VERTEXSEL').type='VERT'
    row.operator("mesh.select_mode", text="Select Edge", icon='EDGESEL').type='EDGE'
    row = box.row(align=True)
    row.operator("mesh.select_mode", text="Select Face", icon='FACESEL').type='FACE'
    prop = row.operator("wm.context_set_value",
                           text="V&E&F Select",
                           icon='OBJECT_DATA')
    prop.value = "(True, True, True)"
    prop.data_path = "tool_settings.mesh_select_mode"
```