# Customizing the new pie menus with commands?

Tags: interface, workflow, pie-menu

I noticed blender recently got updated with maya style radial menus. When I checked it out there was only a few things you could do with them like view and rotate the model or something. Is there any way now to customize the radial menus and put whatever you want in them?

Like could I make a menu for common options that then go into sub menus for like extrude loop select bevel etc... Is there a way to add whatever I want into the radial menus and or create new ones, either through blender naturally now or is there a script to do this?

Comment: Yep, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/16039/599

Comment: Awewsome thanks! mark that as the answer and I'll accept it.